# How to use a 3rd party UI template in an Angular project

Tags: css, angular, templates

I'm trying to use an opensource [angular template](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/argon-design-system-angular) in my angular project. I wan't to know what is the best practice to do this. Should I get the UI source and add that inside my project? or should I do `npm install` this as a dependency?
This template provides only a zip file containing the project files. Can somebody please shed me some light on this. What is the best way to use this template in my angular project ?

Sidenote: I also wish to use [another template](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/argon-dashboard) in my project made for a user dashboard.

Thanks

Comment: The best approach is to take this template as base project. Understand their folder structure and add your logic to this project.

Comment: @Agam Thanks for the quick response. As I mentioned in the side-note, I wish to add another dashboard template. In this case should I combine the two templates into one angular project and start adding my logic?

Comment: In my opinion, we should avoid using more than one component libraries in one project

Comment: In your case, if both of the templates are based on same UI component library, you can copy paste the entire component. If both templates are based on different UI libraries. I would suggest that you convert the components to web component using angular elements. Then you can use it as a native html element in your project.